# What does 'INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit' mean with keras tuner?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-tuner

When I run Keras Tuner search, the code runs for some epochs and then says:
'INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit'.

What does this mean? I am still able to extract best hyperparameters. Is it due to early stopping? I have tried both randomsearch and hyperband.

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this with:

```
tuner = RandomSearch(
    tune_rnn_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    seed=SEED, 
    overwrite=True,
    max_trials=MAX_TRIALS,
    directory='project')
```

To begin a new search and ignore any prior results, we set `overwrite=True`. Alternatively, you can delete the directory folder by using this code:

```
!rm -r <directory folder>
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably the reason is, directory is already created.

Try following steps:

1. Change the directory name.
2. Restart the kernel.
3. re-run all the codes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately your answer doesn't add anything to the most voted one. Please edit it providing additional info and/or a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the **`directory`** argument where you have defined your tuner, or if you have already added **`directory`** arg, try changing the value of that arg.
regard the last line in the below example of `RandomSearch` tuner:

```
tuner = RandomSearch(
    tune_rnn_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    seed=SEED,
    max_trials=MAX_TRIALS,
    directory='**change-this-value**',
)
```

Comment: Tried changing it and still the same message, unfortunately.

Comment: This did solve for me. For some reason I need to delete the directory folder it creates every time I want to run Random search

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by setting these two conditions in my Tuner:

- `overwrite = False`
- a value for `max_trials` in the Oracle greater than the one I used until the error "Oracle triggered exit" occurred (I'm using `kerastuner.oracles.BayesianOptimization` Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue and I found a very easy solution. It can be very easy if you just remove two files from the directory generated by the keras tunner. **oracle.json** and other **.json** files and Run it again it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is occuring because you are working on a small dataset which is resulting in a large number of collisions while performing random search.

Please try reducing the number of 'max-trials' in your random-search, that may fix the issue.

Comment: the max trials is set to 1, and the dataset has 28 features, with 20 000 training instances and 6 000 validation instances. When I run hyperband search it runs some time before getting the message but when i run randomsearch i get the message instantly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Hyperband search.

For me the issue was solved by removing the "Early Stopping" callback from the tuner search.

Answer (score 0):

For me i resolved this issue by removing the hp = HyperParameters() out of the build_model function. I mean, initialize the hp variable outside of the build model function.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I named two hyperparameters with the same names.

E.g., in the build_model(hp) function I had:

```
def build_model(hp):
   ...
   a = hp.Choice('embedding_dim', [32, 64])
   b = hp.Choice('embedding_dim', [128, 256])
   ...
```

A final note is to be careful to have more hyperparameters' combinations that trials. In my example of build_model function I have 4 possible combination of hyperparameters (2*2), so max_trials <= 4.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and didn't find what I was looking for.

If the tuner have finished at trial, that is lower then your max_trial parameter, the most probable reason is that the tuner have already tried all the combinations possible for the field of hyperparameters that you set before.

Example: I have 2 parameters for tuner to try, fist can optain 8 values, second 18. If you multiply these two it gives you 144 combinations and that is exactly the number of trials that the tuner stopped at.